# Difference between maxUploadsize and maxInMemorySize

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

What is the difference betweenn maxUploadSize and maxInMemorySize in CommonsMultiPartResolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**maxUploadSize**: maximum upload size for a single request. That means the total size of all upload files cannot exceed this configured maximum. Default is unlimited (value of -1).   But we can set it by maxUploadSize and its value property.

**maxInMemorySize**: files with size below this value are stored in memory, otherwise they will be stored in disk directly. Default is 10KB (10240 bytes). Or you can customize it by maxInMemorySize and its value property .

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsFileUploadSupport.html):

> **maxUploadSize**: Set the maximum allowed size (in bytes) before uploads are refused. -1 indicates no limit (the default).
>
> **maxInMemorySize**: Set the maximum allowed size (in bytes) before uploads are written to disk. Uploaded files will still be received past this amount, but they will not be stored in memory. Default is 10240, according to Commons FileUpload.